# marker's position don't follow the series when highstock chart is scrolling

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have create a highstock chart with two serieses, when mouse over marker and tooltip will display, don't move the mouse and you can see one of the markers don't follow the series when chart is scrolling.[this is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8FJZ.jpg) How to fix it?

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/sylaince/fz7cv853/3/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
    useUTC: false
  }
});

var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        setInterval(updateData, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'test chart'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'CH1',
    data: []
  }, {
    name: 'CH2',
    data: []
  }]
});

function updateData() {
  t = new Date().getTime();
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    chart.series[i].addPoint([t, Math.random() * 41 - 10], false);
  }
  chart.redraw();
}
```

put your mouse over the top right or bottom right area of the chart would help reproducte the problem.

Comment: It looks like a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: thanks！I'll report it later @KamilKulig